# Do two boolean colums/lists match? Comparison of two different sized colums: Does a part of one list match a part of the other? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, correlation

I have different lists of boolean values in different lengths which I will call `blists`, which I want to compare to a fixed boolean list over time, which I will call `blist`.

The goal is to find the longest matching series in a list (of `blists`) in `blist`.

I want to see if a part or even a whole list of `blists` can be found somewhere in the list of `blist`. I would set a minimum of matching values to not overfill my output.

For example (True = T, False = F, example shorter than in real life):

```
List 1 of blists: (T,T,T,F,T,T,F,F,F,T)

blist: (F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F)
```

I want to see if a part of list 1 `(F,T,T,F,F,F)` equals to some part of the list `blist`.
So for an example blist of `(F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F)` the output should be, that a part of list 1 can be found in `blist`.

So output for example:

`blist` has a similarity with list 1 ((starting point in list 1) 3, (starting point in `blist`) 1, (length) 6, (part of list that matches): `(F,T,T,F,F,F)`

I tried `.corr()` etc., `for`-loops and `if`-conditions and nothing wanted to work properly.

This problem probably has a simple solution, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an implementation that determines where exactly the common list starts at each list, here is a simple "for loop" implementation (I used "0,1" instead of "True and False" for sake of readability. you can convert it easily):

```py
a = [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
b = [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]

list1_start = 0
list2_start = 0
common_list = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)-i):
        for i2 in range(len(b)):
            for j2 in range(len(b)-i2):
                if a[i:i+j] == b[i2:i2+j2]:
                    if len(common_list)<len(a[i:i+j]):
                        common_list = a[i:i+j]
                        list1_start = i+1
                        list2_start = i2+1
                    
print("list1 start: ", list1_start)
print("list2 start: ", list2_start)
print("common_list: ",common_list)
```

the answer:

```
list1 start:  10
list2 start:  3
common_list:  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like the [KMP algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/) to match subset lists in the whole list. It would utilize O(n) complexity. Making a full implementation use worst of O(n^3) but most likely O(n^2). Solution could look like this:

```
longest_match = []

for i in range(len(blists)):
  if(i+len(longest_match) >= len(blists):
    break
  for j in range(i+len(longest_match)+1, len(blists)):
    if(KMPSearch(blists[i,j], blist)):
      longest_match = blists[i,j]
    else:
      break
```

Where you loop through each position in blists and check a subset list starting at i and going one past the length of the longest match already found.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to join the lists into strings and use the "in" and "find" string methods and loops:

```
l1 = ['T','T','T','F','T','T','F','F','F','T']
blist = ['F','F','T','T','F','F','F','F']

w1, bw = ''.join(l1), ''.join(blist)

all_options = sum([[w1[i:ii] for i in range(len(w1))] for ii in range(len(w1))], [])
all_valid_options = [x for x in all_options if (len(x)>1 and x in bw)]
longest_option = sorted(all_valid_options, key=len)[-1]

w1_start = w1.find(longest_option)
w1_end = w1_start + len(longest_option)
bw_start = bw.find(longest_option)
bw_end = bw_start + len(longest_option)
print(longest_option, len(longest_option), (w1_start, w1_end), (bw_start, bw_end))
```

FTTFFF 6 (3, 9) (1, 7)